# Magento - Checkout URL doesn't refresh

Tags: magento, checkout

I'm facing a very strange problem.

AS far as I know, Magento changes the URL at the checkout.
From step 1 to Step 5/6 the URL changes when you go forward or backward. Or if you use continue or the back button, but....

at our installation it stays with "checkout/onepage/" the whole time... It doesn't change.
Does someone has the same problem or does someone got maybe a hint how to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your istallation is OK! 
Different steps at Magento checkout don't have different URLs as whole checkout section is loaded at once (when entering the section) and steps are filled with Ajax.

If you still have any doubts please check the [Demo Store from Magento](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/)

Comment: You are right. Is it somehow possible to display or change the url?

Comment: In Magento almost everything is possible but it is just a matter of skills and the time :) Can you tell why you need such functionallity (if you want f.eg track funnels in Google Analytics you can achieve that without such complicated methods)?